# Bootstrap scrollable column with CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a full height layout and I try to maintain full height column while allowing to scroll its content when it's out of bounds.

Is it possible to do this without using frames, [CSS flex](http://benfrain.com/playground/scroll-test.html) and creating JS code that would calculate something like this: `window.height - ".scrollable".offset.top = ".scrollable".height` ?

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.scrollable {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hpruo87t/

Comment: Is navigation (or anything that's before .scrollable) always the same height?

Comment: I think not, the content above .scrollable may change, e.g. a toolbar can be added, so I'm looking for a generic solution, if it is possible of course.

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/7Ldv3ovp/4/

Comment: Yes, something like that, but without the need to calculate "height: 85vh;" with JS.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8m6vtev6/

Comment: Same thing, I still have to calculate the height of the block to prevent the vertical page scroll.